# magento2 custom observer not getting called with execute()

Tags: magento2

is there any need to override my custom observer.

I have an observer like:

**\Vendor\Module\Observer\MyObserver.php**

```
<?php
 namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
 use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
 use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

 class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
 {

/**
 * @var \Vendor\Module\Model\EngineFactory
 */
protected $tglssearchEngineFactory;


public function __construct(
    \Vendor\Module\Model\Engine $tglssearchEngineFactory

) {
    $this->tglssearchEngineFactory = $tglssearchEngineFactory;

}

  /*  public function createSearchObject(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    echo 'obssr';
    $this->tglssearchEngineFactory->create()->getCatalogResult();
} 
*/

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
 {
    echo 'obssrexe';
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $this->tglssearchEngineFactory->create()->getCatlogSearchResult();
}

 }
```

**etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
 <event name="controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_result_index">
    <observer name="controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_result_handler" instance="vendor\Module\Observer\MyObserver"/> 
</event>
</config>
```

**Is my event name correct?**

**My router frontname:** tgllsearch

**Controller name:** result

**Action:** index

Now in my home page, when i try to search for a keyword for a product, the url gets redirected to

http://localhost:1338/magento2x_2/catalogsearch/result/?q=wirel

which i want it as

http://localhost:1338/magento2x_2/tgllsearch/result/?q=wirel

But from :
catalogsearch/result/?q=wirel
 my echo obssrexe is printing.

Should i have to override my Observer

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to **rewrite controller** of `Magento_CatalogSearch` and not the *Observer*.

Take a look at this topic : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/122774/6643.